# How to call a method of a class that returns a double or string and saves it on a map but as an object

Tags: c++

Compile I get error: cannot convert ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’ to ‘std::map, Object*>::mapped_type {aka Object*}’ in assignment

```
myMap["objectA"] = aa->str();
```

Here's my program:

```
class Object{
public:
    virtual void test() =0;
    virtual string str() {}
};

class A : public Object{
public:
  void test(){
    int a = 23.58;
    cout << a;
  }
  string str(){
    return "a";
  }
};

class B : public Object{
public:
  void test(){
    cout << "B::play()\n";
  }
};

class C : public Object{
public:
  void test(){
    cout << "C::play()\n";
  }
};


int main() {
  map<string, Object*> myMap;

  A* aa = new A;

  myMap["objectA"] = aa->str();
  myMap["objectB"] = new B;
  myMap["objectC"] = new C;

  map<string, Object*>::iterator it;
  for(it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); it++){
    (*it).second->test();
    delete (*it).second;
  }
```

How can I fix the problem to save different types of data on that map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myMap has values of `Object*` since it was declared that way `std::map<std::string, Object*>` you cannot insert in it a string as a value to a certain key.

You must insert a pointer to that object and then access its inner method that will return a string

```
myMap["objectA"] = aa;
cout << myMap["objectA"]->str(); //This will display "a"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a `std::string` as a value to a `std::map<std::string, Object*>`. You can add the pointer `aa`.

```
myMap["objectA"] = aa;
```